# How to delete words on same vertical in vim

Tags: vim

I have the following input in vim:

```
 30 import json
 31 import os
 32 import socket
 33 import subprocess
```

How would I delete everything after the `import` on all four lines?

I thought I could do :

- `30G` to jump to line 30
- `ctrl-v` to enter visual block mode
- `3j` to go down three lines and then
- `dw` to delete the word for each of the items

But that didn't seem to work. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Replace `dw` with `D` to delete to end of line.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons thanks, that's it. Want to put it into an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you were having is that operations such as `d` when in visual mode no longer are associated with motions, but with the selection, so it will just delete what is currently selected without waiting for the `w` motion you wish to give it.

Instead, when in visual block mode, you can use `D` which will delete until the end of the line.

Alternatively, you could use `$` to motion to the end of the line(s) and then `d` to delete the selection.  This way of doing things also allows you to do things like append to the end of the line by doing `$A`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple command

```
:30,33norm welD

 30,33 .............. range
 norm ............... normal mode
 wel ................ jump for beyond the second word
 D .................. delete til the end of line
```